# Get timestamp from a webpage?

Tags: php, string, url, date, timestamp

Is there a way to get the timestamp from a webpage? In this case, news stories webpage. I have tried isolating them in the string contents of the XHTML, but there is too much variation. i have searched all over, but all anyone is able to do is get the current date

Comment: By "timestamp" you mean the "last modified" date?

Comment: yes the webpage goes into a string - I just want to pull the timestamp out. BUt there are millions of timestamps all over in different contexts of XHTML, I was wondering if PHP has a function

Comment: *does* the web page's source code contain a "last modified" timestamp in a `<meta>` tag or something? Because it usually doesn't. That info usually comes through a header that is not visible in the source code. But if it's there, please show in which form so people can suggest a way to filter it out

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the Last-Modified response header. See [for details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) of the full list of headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the header with the code below. Not many websites implement the last-modified date though.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$head = curl_exec($ch); 
?>
```

Comment: interesting. i guess you have to sort through the code - just choose the one that appears most often. i'm decoding news feeds, so the variety in code throws systems off - for instance, Reuter's stories have only 2 common threads - a <focusParagraph> just before the main text and then a </span></span> after the text. But, not always. haah.