# Is there a coding that can find server time of a particular site in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Need to find the exact server time of an particular site(that actually flows or refreshes every millisecond)
If there is a way can you walk me through?

Comment: Unless a web (presumably) server offers this info in their API or other response I don't see how it is possible.

Comment: Not sure, but are you referring to something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712648/get-timestamp-from-a-webpage 
So using `curl` and headers ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do.But you can download a html file using

```
utils::download.file(URL, target_file_path)
```

Comment: I know that there is a typical time for every html site. I just want to grab out that specific data.

Answer (score 0):

Best you can hope for I think is to use some IP Geolocation API to guess the location of said webserver, heuristically determine his timezone and assume a bunch of things, such as:

- the server is using his local timezone (instead of UTC);
- the server's clock is properly synchronised using NTP;
- the server is not located behind reverse proxies in some other location.

If these hold true you have your answer (server time of a given server)